# How to make external file available before the container starts running in AWS ECS fargate cluster

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I am very new to docker, I have a docker file that has all instructions to build a docker image. The image has to be deployed in AWS Fargate cluster. Now I have a python script which does the below things:

```
1. clone a repo from GitHub
2. Locate the docker file, build the image and push the docker image to AWS ecr
3. Create a task definition and deploy into ECS fargate cluster
4. Additionally the script generate a YAML file based on certain logic that has certain parameters(not related to container config) which is required for the application
```

How can I make this file content available to the container before it starts running in  AWS?
I was checking --entrypoint and --cmd, but here I can't change the Dockerfile

Comment: What file specifically are you trying to "make available to the container before it starts running"? The YAML file? It's really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @MarkB The file has some information that is dynamically generated from the script and the yaml file has to be available at runtime. I think when in Fargate service will be deployed that file has to be present inside the container. Is there any way to achieve that without changing the Dockerfile?

Comment: @Daniel Farrell I said it wrong. Correct! Fargate is pulling the image from ecr using the task definition. Basically the dynamically generated file needs to be available at runtime.

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the Dockerfile to include the YAML file in the container. Otherwise you would need to put the file somewhere like S3 and have your application pull it from there when it starts up. You could do a path mapping with EFS, but it's going to be difficult getting the file onto EFS each time it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve that without changing the Dockerfile?

You can't add layers to a docker image without a Dockerfile.  But you can build a *new* image atop the original image, `COPY`ing the file and leaving the `ENTRYPOINT` `CMD` and other configuration as-is.

1. build the "intermediate" image from the upstream Dockerfile, giving it a tag you can refer to later:

   ```
   docker build -t my-intermediate-image:my-version-tag .
   ```
2. Create your yaml file to `myfile.yml`
3. Create a new `Dockerfile.final` that starts `FROM` intermediate:

   ```
   FROM my-intermediate-iamge:my-version-tag
   COPY myfile.yml /expected/yaml/path
   ```
4. Build the final image with a tag for ECS:

   ```
   docker build -f Dockerfile.final -t accountnumber.ecs.amazonaws.com:my-version .
   ```
5. Push the final image tag to ECS
6. Proceed to update the ECS task definition to point to the new image

Comment: If I have to copy the file after creating a base image, can't I edit the Dockerfile from script and that entry `COPY myfile.yml /expected/yaml/path` and then build?In that way I don't need to create any intermediate image.Am I correct?

Comment: Another ask is if I have to change the docker file how can I use `--entrypoint` flag to do the same?

Comment: you can try to edit the existing dockerfile instead if you wish.  `--entrypoint` cannot directly modify the contents of the image before the container starts.  You could specify an entrypoint that used something on the existing image to pull the yaml from an accessible source at container start time, but that's way more complicated than putting it in the image and doesn't satisfy the requirement "before the container starts"